# How to differentiate the abbreviations for preposition and prepositional case in interlinear glossing?

Tags: ambiguity, interlinear-gloss

**How to differentiate the abbreviations for *preposition* and *prepositional case* in interlinear glossing?** It’s both <sup><sub>**PREP**</sub></sup> and still very dissimilar, yet both appear mixed.

Interlinear gloss really helps me in language studies, but in some instances, where prepositions and prepositional case appear equally (yet unrelated) frequently, I’m regularly struggling with their respective abbreviations.

In German, wherein the *[Leipzig Glossing Rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/resources/glossing-rules.php)* lie, it’s just the same (*Präposition↔Präpositiv*).

If one has to rely soley on context, it’d somewhat foil the *raison d’être* of interlinear gloss.

So: **Is there any resolution**<sup>†</sup> **to this ambiguity?**

Or: Is there a reason I seem to be the only one with this issue, like not getting the actual point?

<sup>†</sup>*… like alternative, unambiguous abbreviations like* <sup><sub>**PREADPOS**</sub></sup> *or* <sup><sub>**PREPCASE**</sub></sup>*.*

Comment: Why are you glossing "preposition" in an interlinear gloss? Do you gloss "noun" or "verb"? Shouldn't you instead translate or gloss the meaning of each preposition?

Comment: @curiousdannii I think because prepositions are the hardest to gloss! For example, in "the puppy is pulling at the blanket", this English preposition would translate as the partitive case in Finnish. Other parts of speech don't _tend_ to be nearly as problematic to gloss.